# could not open port /dev/ttyACM0,but i use "sudo chmod 666/dev/ttyACM0“ ，“chmod: "666/dev/tty/ACM0" 后缺少操作数 Try 'chmod --help' for more information.”

Tags: ros, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight dump of console output:

```
$ ROS_NAMESPACE=om_with_tb3 roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch multi_robot_name:=om_with_tb3 set_lidar_frame_id:=om_with_tb3/base_scan
... logging to /home/pi/.ros/log/b64e31c2-5472-11e9-828c-ace01033ad0f/roslaunch-raspberrypi-993.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.43.142:36451/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_core/baud: 115200
 * /om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_core/port: /dev/ttyACM0
 * /om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_core/tf_prefix: om_with_tb3
 * /om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_lds/frame_id: om_with_tb3/base_...
 * /om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_lds/port: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13

NODES
  /om_with_tb3/
    turtlebot3_core (rosserial_python/serial_node.py)
    turtlebot3_diagnostics (turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics)
    turtlebot3_lds (hls_lfcd_lds_driver/hlds_laser_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.43.116:11311

process[om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_core-1]: started with pid [1002]
process[om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_lds-2]: started with pid [1003]
process[om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_diagnostics-3]: started with pid [1004]
[INFO] [1553909289.526154]: ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [1553909289.607560]: Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 115200 baud
[ERROR] [1553909289.627768]: Error opening serial: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'
[om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_core-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pi/.ros/log/b64e31c2-5472-11e9-828c-ace01033ad0f/om_with_tb3-turtlebot3_core-1*.log
^C[om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_diagnostics-3] killing on exit
[om_with_tb3/turtlebot3_lds-2] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320051/could-not-open-port-/dev/ttyacm0,but-i-use-%22sudo-chmod-666/dev/ttyacm0%E2%80%9C--%EF%BC%8C%E2%80%9Cchmod:-%22666/dev/tty/acm0%22-%E5%90%8E%E7%BC%BA%E5%B0%91%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E6%95%B0-try-%27chmod---help%27-for-more-information.%E2%80%9D/) by [berlin](https://answers.ros.org/users/40532/berlin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I had the same issue with port recognition on my tb3 project.

I have also tried chmod but did not work.

I fixed the problem with the help of arduino ide following these instructions http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/controller/opencr10/#arduino-ide    (unit 4)

I hope it helps give it a try!

---

Originally posted by [Panos_Mallioris](https://answers.ros.org/users/40695/panos_mallioris/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0